Why does TikTok's Login Kit not work on Chrome?
I have Login Kit setup on my site which worked fine, but then all of a sudden, it doesn't work on chrome any more. Instead, I get the following error :

When I use the same login url on safari, it takes me to the TikTok login page just fine.
I've tried adding a state value but still no change - it works fine on other browsers, but not Chrome.
Is anyone else experiencing this?

Please show your code. And use Developer Tools to see the actual JavaScript error.

Adblock extensions may interrupt the connection between your browser and the tiktok API. I'd make sure that all adblockers and similar extensions are disabled first

The issue was identified as using an outdated version of TikTok's API. Upon updating to the latest version, v2, the problem was resolved.
